# What Note / Bib citation style uses parenthesis around the publisher?

Tags: style, citations

What citation style is this?

C. van Hoeten, *The Alien in Israelite Law* (Sheffield: JSOT Press, 1991).

D. A. Hubbard, *Beyond Futility* (Grand Rapids, MI: Eerdmans, 1976), pp. 20-21.

J. N. Sevenster, *Paul and Seneca* (Leiden, 1962).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chicago does. That doesn't mean others don't.